# Return a data frame from a function with different length in R

Tags: r, function, n-gram, rbind

I wrote a function that will do unigram and bigrams on a specific column and return them on the same data frame (as rbind),
but I get an error sometimes and I think that because I assigned topfeatures to 30, so if the column can't generate 30 rows for unigram it will return less then 30 for example 15, and the bigrams will return 30, so I will get an error because the function can't rbind and return the datasets if they have different length.

my code:

```
M <- function(L) {
  unigram <- L %>% 
       tokens() %>% 
       tokens_ngrams(n = 1, concatenator = " ") %>% 
       dfm() %>% 
       topfeatures(30)
  df1 <- data.frame(word_unigram = names(unigram), count_unigram = unigram)
  rownames(df1) <- NULL 
  bigram <- L %>% 
       tokens() %>%     
       tokens_ngrams(n = 2, concatenator = " ") %>% 
       dfm() %>% 
       topfeatures(30)
  df2 <- data.frame(word_bigram = names(bigram), count_bigram = bigram)
  rownames(df2) <- NULL

  return(list(df1, df2))
}

datafinal <- data.frame(lapply(data$name, function (L) M(L)))
```

the error:

`Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 30, 19, 10`

so my question is there any way to make a function returns a result even if they not the same lengths by full a NA on it?

Comment: not sure, i think [smartbind](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/smartbind) of gtools could be used for this. i think i used it for the same case like you are asking for. Since you did not provide a reproducible example, i can't try it out

Comment: but how can I use it inside a function? or in the `return(list(df1, df2))` part?